# Flutter (IOS) SqfliteDatabaseException: DatabaseException(open_failed only on IOS 16.2

Tags: ios, flutter, sqflite

After upgrading to IOS 16.2 getting below exception when trying to access database.

on IOS version 16.1 and below everything works fine.

```
SqfliteDatabaseException: DatabaseException(open_failed /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/494EB596-3835-462C-8164-2B773A19A1C4/Documents/main.db)
File "exception_impl.dart", line 11, in wrapDatabaseException
File "database_mixin.dart", line 737, in SqfliteDatabaseMixin.openDatabase
File "database_mixin.dart", line 839, in SqfliteDatabaseMixin.doOpen
File "database.dart", line 46, in SqfliteDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase
File "factory_mixin.dart", line 110, in SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.openDatabase.\<fn\>
...
20 additional frame(s) were not displayed)
```

Platform: IOS
IOS version: 16.2
Device: iPhone 13 pro max.
flutter: 3.3.3

Code: `databaseFactory.openDatabase(path, options: options);`

Plugin: [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

On first launch this exception is thrown,  but if I close app and relaunch it then it works fine.

I checked if database exists also I added additional catch to get database path from both path_provider and sqflite plugin.

```
var documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "main.db");

    try
    {
      await databaseFactory.openDatabase(path, options: options);
    } catch(_) {
      try
      {
        var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
        String path = join(databasesPath, 'main.db');
        return await databaseFactory.openDatabase(path, options: options);
      } catch(e, stackTrace){
        reportException(e, stackTrace);
      }
    }
```